# $\log_2(2 ^{64} - 2^{32}) = 64$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

$\log_2(2^{64} - 2^{32})$

I have tried to do $64 - 32 = 32$ but $\log_2{32} = 5?$

Thx for help in forward advance

Edit: Apologies for my poor spelling and grammar. Please forgive me. I am new to this forum and I joined in because I want to be smart so I can get 6 in gcse maths.

Comment: Do you mean $\log_2(2^{64}-2^{32})?$

Comment: Yes I do mean that sorry I don't know how to write in calculator :(

Comment: You should look at this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I'll edit this post for you and afterwards you can look to see how I changed it.

Comment: $\log_2 2^{64}=64$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log_2(2^{64}-2^{32})$ is very close to $64$ -- so close that the difference may not show on the calculator you're using. With a high-precision calculator I get

$$ \log_2(2^{64}-2^{32}) = 63.999\,999\,999\,664\,096\,384\,7\ldots $$

---

We can predict this without calculating in detail, because
$$ 2^{64}-2^{32} = 2^{64}(1-2^{-32}) $$
and therefore
$$ \log_2(2^{64}-2^{32}) = 64 + \log_2(1-2^{-32}) $$
Here $1-2^{-32}$ is very close to $1$, so its logarithm is very close to $0$ and hardly makes a dent in the $64$.

For a next approximation we can write
$$ \log_2(2^{64}-2^{32}) = 64 + \log_2(1-2^{-32}) 
= 64 + \frac{\ln(1-2^{-32})}{\ln 2} $$
and use the approximation $\ln(1+x)\approx x$ when $x$ is small. Here we have $x=-2^{-32}$ which is certainly small, so
$$ \log_2(2^{64}-2^{32}) \approx 64 - \frac{2^{-32}}{\ln 2} \approx 
63.999\,999\,999\,664\,096\,385\,0 $$
which is extremely close to the result above.

Comment: So how comes \log_2(2^{64} - 2^{32}) - log_2(2^{64}) is still 64?

Comment: @Forppppppppppppppppppppppp How did you get that answer?

Comment: @Forp: It isn't. It should be about $\frac{1}{2^{32} \ln 2}$.

Comment: Thankyou!!!! 1!!1!1 papu will b proud!!!!

Comment: Who is papu ?..

Comment: He is the person that lives in my cupboard

Comment: Okay, I try to assume good faith, but this looks like we're just dealing with a troll.

Comment: Sorry not cupboard I meant complex

Comment: How dare you, getting a grade 6 isn't easy you know ❤️